# Is it possible to have a java object in log4j Conversion pattern?

Tags: log4j

Its multi tenancy application and generates lots of logs.

I want to see tenant information in an individual log statement.
I have the tenant information in my thread context.

How can i configure log4j to add tenant information to log statements by default.

I saw Conversion pattern says the pattern of log4j messages like %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n.
 It didnt helped, not able to print thread context in it.

Say CurrentThread.getTenantName() gives me the current tenant, how could add it to log4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In log4j , patterns parsed by [PatternParser](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/PatternParser.html)

You can write your own parser by overriding it and parse custom literal like %i where "i" will denote tenant id in your case.

Please refer below blog for creating custom literal and parser
http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.in/2010/07/creating-log4j-custom-patternlayout.html